# Coding4fun Toolkit AboutPrompt declared in XAML?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use the coding4fun AboutPrompt declared in XAMl instead of C#. 
I need something like this in my MainPage.XMAL:

```
<c4fControls:AboutPrompt x:Name="prompt" Visibility="Collapsed" Title="AboutPrompt declared in XAML" WaterMark="No Watermark">
                <c4fControls:AboutPrompt.Body>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is the first tect in the Body section."/>
                </c4fControls:AboutPrompt.Body>
            </c4fControls:AboutPrompt>
```

After that i want to show the AboutPrompt in the standard way:

```
 private void aboutPrompt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

                    prompt.Visibility = visibility.Visible;
                    prompt.Show();
    }
```

The problem is that I get the *Element is already the child of another element.* exception.

I know that I can use the VisualTreeHelper to workaround this but I need an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `AboutPrompt` control is designed to be used with a fixed set of inputs: either a an author anme, twitter name, email address, and website URL, or a list `AboutPersonItem[]` instances, which are then rendered in the content of the popup.

If you want a customized about prompt that does not follow the Coding4Fun `AboutPrompt` style, then I would suggest that you use the `Popup<T, TPopupResult>` class instead.

There's a translation of an [Italian blog post](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/BV.aspx?ref=IE8Activity&a=http%3A%2F%2Fqmatteoq.tostring.it%2Fblog%2Fpost%2Fcoding4fun-una-nuova-libreria-di-microsoft-per-lo-sviluppo-di-applicazioni-per-windows-phone-7-parte-1-i-controlli-1-parte) and an [overview of the Coding4Fun toolkit](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Coding4Fun-Toolkit-for-WP7-Overview-and-Getting-Started) which both discuss the `AboutPrompt` if you need any further help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually here is an in depth article about the AboutPrompt and a workaround with UserControl:http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-AboutPrompt-in-depth

Comment: Glad you got where you needed to. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out with a simple UserControl. (I mean setting the Body content of the AboutPrompt)